# How do I print MODLUS " % " in java

Tags: java, syntax, modulo

I want to output a literal `%` instead of `"mod"` in the following code:

```
System.out.printf("Result of Modulus of %d mod %d is %d\n", num1, num2, (num1 % num2));
```

ie I want the output to be `"Result of Modulus of 4 % 2 is 0"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can escape `%` in format strings with another `%`.

```java
System.out.printf("The result of %d %% %d is %d", n1, n2, n1 % n2);
```